# Which part of a pnp-transistor is the buried layer connected to?

Tags: transistors, pnp

I am preparing for exam and one of the questions is this: "Which part of a **pnp**-transistor is the **Buried  Layer** normally connected to?"

According to the lecture notes handed out, the correct answer is: **base**
According to [the IEEE](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=31688&contentType=Journals%20&%20Magazines) (the title being "*p-n-p heterojunction bipolar transistors with buried subcollector layers*"), the correct answer is: **collector**

Which answer is correct?

Comment: Note: I might be completely off course in interpreting the title of the IEEE abstract

Comment: the link doesn't work for me, but articles on IEEE XPlore are usually academic journal articles. They don't necessarily represent common practice or the consensus of IEEE members. They're just a report by one academic (or group) on one particular experiment or study.

Comment: Also, "heterojunction bipolar transistors" indicates a special kind of transistor, probably in a material other than silicon. It won't reflect at all on what's normally done in silicon BJT's, which are what your question asks when it asks about what's "normally" done.

Comment: When for the a class, the instructor's answer is always right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia article has a nice illustration of the [structure of a typical npn transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_transistor#Structure).
The structure of a typical pnp transistor has many similarities.

In particular, both of them have:
A thin surface layer acts as the emitter.
A thin layer buried under the emitter acts as the base.
The substrate -- the bulk material all the way to the bottom surface -- acts as the collector.

As The Photon pointed out,
the vast majority of PNP and NPN transistors are
[planar transistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/planar_transistor)
made entirely of doped silicon.
So any question that asks about "PNP transistor",
you are safe to assume unless the question specifically says otherwise
that it's *not* talking about the rarely-used [heterojunction bipolar transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterojunction_bipolar_transistor).

Comment: Question is, if the npn have the collector as the buried layer, why does the pnp have the base as the buried layer? I know the answer, but not authoritatively. I think this is key to OP's question.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Huh? Normal planar transistors -- both npn and pnp -- have the base as the buried layer.

Comment: Ah. Ignore my comment. I made a wrong guess about words for the different layers of a BJT.